# Получить определенный виджет из леаута, который находится внутри другого лейаута

Tags: c++, qt5

Всем привет! Такой вопрос, как мне достать определенный виджет из лойаута.

Например у меня есть такая конструкция:

```
QHBoxLayout * pLayout = new QHBoxLayout(parent);
QRadioButton * item = new QRadioButton(parent);
QPushButton * button = new QPushButton(parent);
pLayout->addWidget(item);
pLayout->addWidget(button);
layout->addLayout(pLayout);
```

И мне нужно достать из этой конструкции радиобаттон, например так:

```
for (size_t i = 0, sz = N; i < sz; ++i)
{
    QWidget * selectorWidget = layout->itemAt((int)i)->widget();
}
QRadioButton* item  = qobject_cast<QRadioButton*>(selectorWidget);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать поиск потомка `findChild` по имени объекта:

```
//MainWindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QPushButton>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QVBoxLayout * vLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout * pLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    QRadioButton * item = new QRadioButton();
    item->setObjectName("radioBtn");
    QPushButton * button = new QPushButton();
    button->setObjectName("pushBtn");
    pLayout->addWidget(item);
    pLayout->addWidget(button);
    vLayout->addLayout(pLayout);
    centralWidget()->setLayout(vLayout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Поиск элементов по имени:

```
//main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QRadioButton>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    QPushButton* el = w.centralWidget()->findChild<QPushButton*>("pushBtn");
    if (el){
        el->setEnabled(false);
    }else{
        qInfo() << "can't find push";
    }
    QRadioButton* radioBtn = w.centralWidget()->findChild<QRadioButton*>("radioBtn");
    if (radioBtn){
        radioBtn->setChecked(true);
    }else{
        qInfo() << "can't find radio";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

Вместо конкретных типов кнопок можно указывать параметров шаблона `QWidget*`, а потом в зависимости от `objectName` делать `qobject_cast` к нужному типа кнопки.